# About non linear operation in manifold learning

Tags: machine-learning, data-science

I am reading about Manifold learning at following link

https://github.com/jakevdp/PythonDataScienceHandbook/blob/master/notebooks/05.10-Manifold-Learning.ipynb

Here in non-linear operation author mentioned as below

> The fundamental relationships between the data points are still there,
>   but this time the data has been transformed in a nonlinear way: it has
>   been wrapped-up into the shape of an "S." The best two-dimensional
>   linear embedding does not unwrap the S-curve, but instead throws out
>   the original y-axis.

My questions on above text are
1. What does author mean by "wrapped-up in to shape of an "S"?
2. What does author mean by "linear embedding does not unwrap the S-curve, but instead throws out the original y-axis."?

I am new to machine learning and learning stuff by following this book on myself. Kindly explain.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

The author tries to give an example where a linear projection (in this case with MDS) of your data fails.

The *fundamental relationship* of your data points is that the datapoints shape the  word "HELLO" and each datapoint belongs to a character of the word (indicated by color). *Wrapped-up in to shape of an S* means, we add an additional dimension (say z) to our points by transforming x- and y-coordinates in a non-linear fashion (see funtion `make_hello_s_curve`).

Now the idea is to use MDS to eliminate a dimension, such that "a low-dimensional representation of the data in which the distances respect well the distances in the original high-dimensional space" [[1](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/manifold.html#multidimensional-scaling)] is found. Thus our data should again be  distinguishable as the word "HELLO", this is what's meant by *unwrap*. However since this is a example where MDS fails, we see that the lower-dimensional representation it found is the S-curve (see image in `In [14`) and HELLO is no longer distinguishable "and we lose track of the fundamental relationships in the embedded manifold". The reason for this is the non-linear transformation we applied earlier.

I hope that sheds some light on the problem. Have a look at the MDS [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/manifold.html#multidimensional-scaling) of sklearn as well to see what it's all about. Maybe post your question also on [datascience.stackexchange.com](http://datascience.stackexchange.com).